# D3 draw lines around a pie with a circular rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given a pie chart with an arc, I'd like to append lines at each arcs center points to follow the path. I'm able to append the lines on the path properly currently but I'm not able to angle them appropriately. I have a set of circles going around my pie chart and need to place these lines slightly below the circles at the mid point between 1 circle and the next. Here is a pretty gross image of what I'm trying to do, the lines should be at the center of the arc but just below the circles and following the path of the arc.
[image: D3 lines around a pie chart]

And here is what I am currently getting with my code.I'm trying to get the dark black lines to follow a similar rotation to the light gray ones that you see at the center.

[image]

```js
const startAngle = (-45 * Math.PI) / 180;
const endAngle = (-45 * Math.PI) / 180 + 2 * Math.PI;
const width = 500;
const height = Math.min(width, 500);
const viewBox = [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height];

const svg = d3
    .select("#canvas")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", viewBox);

function drawGridDonut(svg, innerFactor, outerFactor) {
  const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  const graph = new Array(6); // 6 equal sections

  const gridPie = d3
    .pie()
    .startAngle(startAngle)
    .endAngle(endAngle)
    .sort(null)
    .value(1);

  const arc = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * innerFactor)
    .outerRadius(radius * outerFactor);

  // base path + arc
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(gridPie(graph))
    .join("path")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("d", arc);

  // border lines
  svg
    .selectAll(".grid")
    // border lines, 1 = dark border, 0 = light border
    .data(gridPie([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]))
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr(
      "y2",
      d =>
        Math.sin(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) *
        (radius - (d.data === 1 ? 0 : 75.5))
    )
    .attr(
      "x2",
      d =>
        Math.cos(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) *
        (radius - (d.data === 1 ? 0 : 75.5))
    )
    .attr("stroke", d => (d.data === 0 ? "#C8C8C8" : "#000"))
    .attr("stroke-width", "0.1");


  // dots for overuse + benefits
  svg
    .selectAll(".dot")
    .data(gridPie([...Array(12)]))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('class', '.dot')
    .attr("cx", d => arc.centroid(d)[0])
    .attr("cy", d => arc.centroid(d)[1])
    .attr("r", 1)
    .style("fill", "#C8C8C8");

// this is where the lines are being made
  svg
      .selectAll('.hash')
      .data(gridPie([...Array(12)]))
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('class', '.hash')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr("x1", (d) => arc.centroid(d)[0] - d.startAngle)
      .attr("y1", (d) => arc.centroid(d)[1] - d.startAngle)
      .attr('x2', d =>  arc.centroid(d)[0] + d.endAngle )
      .attr('y2', d => arc.centroid(d)[1] + d.endAngle)
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 4)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr('transform', (d) => 'rotate(180)')

}

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  drawGridDonut(svg, 0.9 - 0.04, 0.9 + 0.002)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by drawing a line from the center of my pie to the top then adding dasharray (with fine tuning of the inner and outer arcs to mark the safe spaces.

```
function drawHyphen(svg, innerFactor, outerFactor, dashPercent) {
  const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  const gridPie = d3
    .pie()
    .startAngle(startAngle)
    .endAngle(endAngle)
    .sort(null)
    .value(1);

  svg
  .selectAll('.line')
  .data(gridPie([...Array(12)]))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr('class', (d, i) => `line${i}`)
  .attr(
    "y1",
    d =>
      Math.sin((d.startAngle) - Math.PI / 4) * radius * innerFactor
  )
  .attr(
    "x1",
    d =>
      Math.cos((d.startAngle) - Math.PI / 4) * radius * innerFactor
  )
  .attr(
    "y2",
    d =>
      Math.sin((d.startAngle) - Math.PI / 4) * radius / outerFactor
  )
  .attr(
    "x2",
    d =>
      Math.cos((d.startAngle) - Math.PI / 4) * radius / outerFactor
  )
  .attr("stroke", "#EEEEEE")
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", `0.5, ${dashPercent}`)
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
}
```

then I call the function as many times as I need to and set the outerFactor to be the threshold where the safe space will be.

```
let outerArc = 1 - 0.051
 drawHyphen(svg, outerArc - 0.835, outerArc - 2.3, "1.9%")
```